# GeoJSON object naming convention

Tags: json, rest, geojson

A GeoJSON object might look something like this:

```
{
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
        28.169778, 
        -25.886587
    ]
}
```

We may embed this into some other resource object, say a 'point of interest':

```
{
    "id": "1266f0WqVkGB2BnnVhOvEw",
    "name": "Eco Fushion, Witch-Hazel Ave",
    "type": "TRANSIT",
    "code": "ert222",
    "point": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            28.169778, 
            -25.886587
        ]
    }
}
```

**Is there any convention as to what this GeoJSON object should be named as when embedded as a field?**

In the above example, I have called it `point`.